# make error: undefined reference to cpp_redis::client::set(..) and cv::Mat::~Mat()

Tags: c++, cmake, g++

Complete error stack trace:

```
undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int, void*, unsigned long)'
undefined reference to `cv::imencode(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
undefined reference to `cpp_redis::client::client()'
undefined reference to `cpp_redis::client::connect(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, std::function<void (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, cpp_redis::connect_state)> const&, unsigned int, int, unsigned int)'
undefined reference to `cpp_redis::client::set(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
undefined reference to `cpp_redis::client::sync_commit()'
undefined reference to `cpp_redis::client::~client()'
undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
undefined reference to `cpp_redis::client::~client()'
undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/sensors/camera/camera/CMakeFiles/sample_camera.dir/build.make:130: recipe for target 'src/sensors/camera/camera/sample_camera' failed
make[2]: *** [src/sensors/camera/camera/sample_camera] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2246: recipe for target 'src/sensors/camera/camera/CMakeFiles/sample_camera.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/sensors/camera/camera/CMakeFiles/sample_camera.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is the code snippet which is causing `make` to fail:

```cpp
        std::vector<uchar> buf; 
        cv::Mat matImage = cv::Mat(imgCPU->prop.width, imgCPU->prop.height, CV_8UC3, imgCPU->data[0]);
        cv::imencode(".jpg", matImage, buf);
        
        cpp_redis::client client;
        client.connect();
        client.set("image", {buf.begin(), buf.end()});
        client.sync_commit();
```

Note that
`imgCPU->prop.width, imgCPU->prop.height` are ints and

`imgCPU->data[0]` is `uint8_t *`.

What changes should I make in the `CMakeLists.txt` file for my program to compile correctly?

Here is what my CMakeLists.txt file looks:

```
project(sample_camera C CXX)
pkg_check_modules(OPENCV opencv)
if(${OPENCV_FOUND})
MESSAGE("OPENCV_FOUND:" ${OPENCV_FOUND})
MESSAGE("OPENCV_VERSION:" ${OPENCV_VERSION})
MESSAGE("OPENCV_LIBRARIES:" ${OPENCV_LIBRARIES})
MESSAGE("OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS:" ${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
MESSAGE("OPENCV_LIBRARY_DIRS:" ${OPENCV_LIBRARY_DIRS})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/include/opencv4")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2")
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${OPENCV_LIBRARY_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES("/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2")
endif()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project files
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set(PUBLIC_DOCS
    README.md
)

set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
)

set(LIBRARIES
    ${Driveworks_LIBRARIES}
    samples_framework
    lodepng-src
)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Final target
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${LIBRARIES})
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY FOLDER "Samples")

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Install target
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sdk_add_sample(${PROJECT_NAME})
sdk_add_sample_data(${PROJECT_NAME} "samples/sensors/camera/camera")
```

Comment: it looks like that you didn't include in your make file the cpp files with implementations of  `cv::Mat` and `cpp_redis::client`

Comment: Do you mean I have to add `/home/lidar/Documents/cpp_redis/sources/core/client.cpp` and `/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp` file names in CMakeLists.txt under set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
)

Comment: If they are part of some external library you don't have to add the cpp file but the object file of the library into the linker part of your make file

Comment: your issue is not knowing what "linking" is. the issue is not specific to those libraries. I'll remove those tags.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12573818/1387438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CMakeLists.txt` is wrong and messy try this:

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(DisplayImage CXX)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED COMPONENTS core imgproc video)

...
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PRIVATE
        opencv_core 
        opencv_video
        opencv_imgproc)
```

Drop `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and `LINK_DIRECTORIES` since it is obsolete (wrong) in [modern CMake](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/intro/dodonot.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marek. That issue is resolved now. I'm unable to upvote due to low reputation.